# How to use aggregate at deep nested array element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My document structure like this:

```
{
"_id": 123,
"city": '010',
"tags": [
    {
        "tgi": 101.1396,
        "tag": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "tgi": 177,
                "tag": "aa",
                "children": [
                    {
                       tgi: 109.13,
                       tag: 'xx-xx',
                       children: []
                    },
                    {...}, 
                    ...
                ]
            },
            {
                "tgi": 100,
                "tag": "bb",
                "children": [
                    {
                       tgi: 109.13,
                       tag: 'yy-yy',
                       children: []
                    },
                    {...}, 
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
  ]
},
{
    "_id": 124,
    "city": '020',
    "tags": ...
},
...
```

The 'tags' is deep nested, every document has the same structure (all have tgi,tag and children).

Now I want to sort by tgi in such deep nested array, such as 'tags.children.children.tgi' with 'tags.children.children.tag' equal 'yy-yy'.

How can I solve such a complicated problem?

Comment: use $unwind, $unwind does is allow you to peel off a document for each element and returns that resulting document.  { $unwind : "$tags" }, { $unwind : "tags.children" }

Comment: Yeah, I just try to calculate depth of children for $unwind field, and it works.